# The C Programming Language Exercise 1-9 Problem

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

i am doing this C exercise and i can't make it work.
Any clues as to what am i doing wrong? (I am trying not to use either scanf or printf)

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string
> of one or more blanks by a single blank.

```
int main()
{
    int currentChar;
    int wasBlank = 0;
    while((currentChar = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (currentChar != ' ') {
            if (wasBlank) {
               putchar(' ');
               putchar(currentChar);
            }
            putchar(currentChar);
        }
        else
            wasBlank = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wasBlank is never reset. It needs to be reset to 0 when you read a non-space char.

Comment: You also have a missing else.

Comment: Ahhh right. That solved it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

["wasBlank ... needs to be reset to 0 when you read a non-space char. "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532775/the-c-programming-language-exercise-1-9-problem#comment112345259_63532775) is a good first idea, but does not solve the case when the last character before `EOF` is a single blank.

Print the blank when first seen, not repeated ones.

```
int main(void) {
  int previousChar = EOF;
  int currentChar;
  while((currentChar = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (currentChar != ' ' || previousChar != ' ') {
      putchar(currentChar);
    }
    previousChar = currentChar;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP’s question wasn’t “can you write this program” but rather “why does my program fail?”

Comment: @Caleb "wasBlank ... needs to be reset to 0 when you read a non-space char" explains the failure.  This answer explains why the linked comment's implied fix is insufficient.  Then shows a fix.